# Date conversion as.yearmon

Tags: r, date, date-conversion

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
library(zoo)
head(monthly.station6)

                    [,1]
1995-02-28 00:00:00 2.07
1995-03-01 00:00:00 5.70
1995-04-30 01:00:00 0.65
1995-05-31 01:00:00 1.03
1995-06-30 01:00:00 0.77
1995-07-31 01:00:00 0.39
```

I am applying this code: `monthly.station6[,0] <- as.yearmon(monthly.station6[,0])` to try to convert this into a year month format, but I think the fact that the date column is [,0] is preventing it? Not sure where I am going wrong, any help would be appreciated!

```
head(monthly.station6)

             [,1]
Feb 1995 2.07
Mar 1995 5.70
Apr 1995 0.65
May 1995 1.03
Jun 1995 0.77
Jul 1995 0.39
```

as requested `dput(head(monthly.station6))`:

```
structure(c(2.07, 5.7, 0.65, 1.03, 0.77, 0.39), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "", class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), index = structure(c(793929600, 794016000, 799200000, 
801878400, 804470400, 807148800), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .Dim = c(6L, 1L))
```

Comment: There is no 0 index.  You need to apply on the row.names i.e. `as.yearmon(as.POSIXct(row.names(monthly.station6)))`

Comment: @akrun when I call `monthly.station6[,0] it outputs the dates; but that code does not work, it errors and says "Error in as.POSIXct.default(row.names(monthly.station6)) : 
  do not know how to convert 'row.names(monthly.station6)' to class “POSIXct”"

Comment: @Zheyuan Li yes I think it's a zoo object - I'm guessing that makes a difference then!

Comment: Try `xts(monthly.station6, order.by=as.yearmon(strftime(index(monthly.station6), format="%Y-%m))`. This should convert the `index` of your `xts` to `yearmon`.

Comment: Thanks guys, that completely resolves it! Fantastic help as always :)

Comment: Just to let you know that you don't need the internal `strftime` to convert the `index` to a string first. You can just use: `xts(monthly.station6, order.by=as.yearmon(index(monthly.station6)))`. Sorry about that and the typos in the first comment, but you seem to have overcame my deficiencies :-) Also, you need to be a bit careful with this as `order.by` for `xts` must be unique. See `?xts`.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @aichao. Out of interest, could I do something similar for showing only the year?

Comment: Take a look at `?yearmon`. At the end of the examples, they define a function: `as.year <- function(x) as.numeric(floor(as.yearmon(x)))`, which can be used to convert the index to years. But again, I believe that `order.by` needs to be unique so that you need the original index to only have one observation per year or you would want to `aggregate` the data by year.

Answer (score 0):

**1) index** The object's class is `"xts"`, not `"data.frame"`.  Use `index` (or `time`) to modify `monthly.station6`:

```
library(xts)
index(monthly.station6) <- as.yearmon(index(monthly.station6))
```

**2) aggregate.zoo** Another possibility is to use `aggregate.zoo`.  That will return a `"zoo"` object so convert it back to `"xts"` :

```
library(xts)
as.xts(aggregate(monthly.station6, as.yearmon))
```

**3) fortify.zoo** Since the question mentions data.frame, if what you really wanted was a data.frame then the first statement after `library` will create a data.frame with a first column of `Index` and the second will perform the conversion to `"yearmon"`:

```
library(xts)
DF <- fortify.zoo(monthly.station6)
transform(DF, Index = as.yearmon(Index))
```

**Note:** If you want just year then it cannot be an xts object but you could represent it as a data.frame.  Using `DF` from (3):

```
transform(DF, Index = as.numeric(format(Index, "%Y")))
```